# You have an error in your SQL syntax - near 'left)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, reserved-words

I'm a newbie in the php programming.

I would like to apply an insert query but I get this error :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'left) VALUES ('****df','****2135gh','***@yahoo.com' at line 2"}

```
$sql_insert_new_user = "insert into users (username,password,email,status,finance,province,city,address,tell,
mobile,admin_seen,type,left) VALUES ('$username','$password','$email',1,0,$town,$city,
'$address','$telephone','$mobile',0,'employe',0)";

            mysql_query($sql_insert_new_user);
            $error = mysql_error();
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/4193263). Prefer using Prepared Statements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`left` is a reserved word and in the query you need escape with backtics

```
`left`
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: ...or better, change the column name to something like `lft`

Comment: Yeah @HoboSapiens I agree but its really hard to maintain it since the reserved words will often may get added with every newer version of mysql. Once approach is to always back-tics the column name into the query so that any word I am using today if it becomes reserved tomorrow my query will not fail.

Answer (score 0):

left  is a reserved word and in the query you need  to use like this for all reserved word
   '`left`'

This gives all the details about reserved word https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql_insert_new_user = "insert into users (username,password,email,status,finance,province,city,address,tell,
mobile,admin_seen,type,`left`) VALUES ('$username','$password','$email',1,0,$town,$city,
'$address','$telephone','$mobile',0,'employe',0)";
```

Comment: Great answer. Except I have no idea why you have posted this code.

Comment: @ Hobo Sapiens what does it mean?

Comment: `left` is a reserved word in MySQL, so you need to enclose it in backticks if you want to use it as a column name

Comment: @vivek It would help it you included a little explanation in your code, to show what is/was wrong and how did you fix it

Answer (score -1):

`left` is a mysql reserved word. So you have to rename the column `left`.

See here : [reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html) for furhter information